# Validate one node based on criteria from another node by referencing the criteria's @ID

Tags: xml, validation, schematron

I am trying to validate the presence of a child element based on criteria in a different element in the document identified by its ID. Using ISO Schematron and XPath 2.0.

Take the following example:

```
<value id="red" bits="16" />

<foo value_id="red">
    <increased_sensitivity/>
</foo>
```

The element "increased_sensitivity" should only be allowed if a "value" element with the @id "red" contains the attribute bits="16" somewhere in the document.

To be completely honest, im not even certain this is possible with Schematron, my experience with it is quite limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the value element whose ID matches the foo id value ("red" in this case), and then inspect the bits value there, then this Schematron schema shows one way it could be done:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">

  <sch:let name="root" value="/"/>

  <sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="increased_sensitivity">
      <sch:let name="id" value="parent::*/@value_id"/>
      <sch:let name="assoc-bits-value" value="$root//value[@id=$id]/@bits"/>
      <sch:assert test="$assoc-bits-value = 16">When the increased_sensitivity element is used, a
        corresponding value element must exist in the doucment with a bits value of
        "16".</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
  </sch:pattern>

</sch:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, I now realize I wasn't quite clear in my question. The schema rule needs to match whatever the specified value_id is for an occurrence of the foo element, not specifically a "red" id. The @value_id is schemaed in xsd:IDREF, and thus could be any ID defined elsewhere in the document.

Comment: I realized that was what you probably meant as I read it back - the answer now does what you want I think! :-)

Comment: Ah yes, not only does that work, it exposes a much better technique I can use to figure out a couple other problems I am stuck on. Thank you greatly.